# Oneplus Nord file manager not able to open intent

Tags: file-system, file-management, android-12, oneplus

On my Oneplus Nord I have multiple apps that aren't able to open a file manager to let me select files. There would be the Cryptomator app giving me the following error in their debug logs:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE }
    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2114)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1770)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5473)
    at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:597)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5426)
    at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:583)
    at org.cryptomator.presentation.presenter.Presenter.requestActivityResult(Presenter.kt:214)
    at org.cryptomator.presentation.presenter.CloudConnectionListPresenter.openDocumentTree(CloudConnectionListPresenter.kt:167)
    at org.cryptomator.presentation.presenter.CloudConnectionListPresenter.onAddConnectionClicked(CloudConnectionListPresenter.kt:128)
    at org.cryptomator.presentation.ui.fragment.CloudConnectionListFragment.setupView$lambda-0(CloudConnectionListFragment.kt:41)
    at org.cryptomator.presentation.ui.fragment.CloudConnectionListFragment.$r8$lambda$pNdBGyr2z2kiliHSZlRXLnVhB8A(Unknown Source:0)
    at org.cryptomator.presentation.ui.fragment.CloudConnectionListFragment$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7488)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7464)
    at android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:841)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28911)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:233)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:344)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8212)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:584)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1034)
```

In the app NewPipe if I want to select a folder on where to download videos to it says `No suitable file manager was found for this action. Please install a storage access framework compatible file manager`. There I was not able to get a detailed error message but I assume it's about the same. Since this appears in these two apps (and some others I have uninstalled) I assume this is a problem with the stock ROM of the Onplus Nord. I have the latest Version with Android 12 installed. I tried multiple filemanager apps from the playstore but none so far worked for all the apps.

However the [Material Files](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.zhanghai.android.files&hl=gsw&gl=US) App lets me use KeePassDX. Without that app I get a similar error message there aswell.

Is there any solution that gets rid of the error in all apps? The phone isn't rooted.

Comment: Did you disable "Files" app at some point? Check Settings app to find this app and see if it is enabled or not.

Comment: In the section `Deactivated Apps` there is only Google Pay

Comment: Have you tried [Files by Google](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.nbu.files) or [Solid Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.solidexplorer2)?

Comment: I installed both, still getting the same error message :(